# How to apply xslt for-each to attributes?

Tags: xslt, saxon

My XML document looks like this-

```
<doc>

  <system_data>
    <registry_item id="1">
      <hive>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE</hive>
    </registry_item>
    <file_item id="2">
      <filepath>C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll</filepath>    
    </file_item>
  </system_data>

</doc>
```

I would like to transform it such as "id" attribute value is incremented sequentially e.g :

```
<doc>

  <system_data>
    <registry_item id="10">
      <hive>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE</hive>
    </registry_item>
    <file_item id="11">
      <filepath>C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll</filepath>    
    </file_item>
  </system_data>

</doc>
```

I am using the "[identity](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)" design and my xsl looks like this-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:import href="Identity.xsl"/>
<xslt:param name="newID" />
  <xsl:template match="//system_data/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="number($newID)+1"/>      
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>   
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am passing newID value as "10". How to I select each attribute and increment its value?

Indentity.xsl looks like this-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Whenever you match any node or any attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply xsl, I am getting following error-

```
An attribute node (id) cannot be created after the children of the containing element
```

Comment: hi there, are you able to help with a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289248/xslt-attribute-node-id-cannot-be-created-after-the-children-of-the-containing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your template for `match="//system_data/*"` to this:

```
  <xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="number($newID)+count(preceding::*/@id)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: are you able to help with a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289248/xslt-attribute-node-id-cannot-be-created-after-the-children-of-the-containing