# XSLT attribute node (id) cannot be created after the children of the containing element

Tags: html, xslt, weblogic, weblogic12c

Typically i am doing an XSLT process over a Weblogic12 server. I kept running into this issue

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: An attribute node 
(id) cannot be created after the children of the containing element
```

Before the migration, our team had no problems at all...

Any idea why? i recently upgraded from BEA Weblogic3 to Oracle Enterprise Weblogic 12. Or am i missing a library?

This is plaguing our entire team! Thanks!

EDIT 1:

Error points to `<xsl:attribute name="id">` in `<xsl:template name="makeErrorDiv">`

```
<td>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@colspan | @align | @style | @valign | @class | @id | @name"/>
            <xsl:if test="@colspan = '1' and $columnWidth != '' and not(@suppressColWidth='true')"><xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="$columnWidth"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@rowspan != '1'"><xsl:copy-of select="@rowspan"/></xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="descendant::ErrMsg">
                <xsl:call-template name="makeErrorDiv"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </td>


<xsl:template name="makeErrorDiv">      
        <div style="display:none;">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="descendant::*[ParentId]">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="descendant::ParentId[position() = 1]"/><![CDATA[$err]]></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>         
                <xsl:when test="descendant::*[ErrMsg][Name]">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="descendant::*[ErrMsg][position() = 1]/Name"/><![CDATA[$err]]></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(descendant::*[ErrMsg])">
                    <xsl:variable name="name"><xsl:value-of select="descendant::*[Name][position() = 1]/Name"/></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="parsed"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($name, '!')"/></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><!--error here! -->
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$parsed = ''"><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$parsed"/></xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:text><![CDATA[$err]]></xsl:text></xsl:attribute>   
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="descendant::*[ErrMsg][not(Name)]">
                    <xsl:variable name="name"><xsl:value-of select="descendant::*[Name][position() = 1]/Name"/></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="parsed"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($name, '!')"/></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$parsed = ''"><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$parsed"/></xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:text><![CDATA[$err]]></xsl:text></xsl:attribute>                   
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>   
            <span style="color: #FF0000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;"><xsl:value-of select="descendant::ErrMsg[position() = 1]"/></span>
        </div>      
    </xsl:template>
```

XML sample...not sure if it's helpful...the entire XML file is 1000+ lines

```
<DisclosureRowColor template="OneColumn" position="8" lastPosition="30" colCount="4" color1="#F2F8FE" color2="#ffffff">
                <Cell colspan="1">
                    <ListBox onchange="toggleAddressByAjax();">
                        <Name>APPLICATION_CUSTOMER.EMPLOYED_SINCE_MM!YLI</Name>
                        <Size>1</Size>
                        <Default rtexprvalue="true">mb.getValue("APPLICATION_CUSTOMER.EMPLOYED_SINCE_MM!YLI", "A")</Default>
                        <Map rtexprvalue="true">mb.getGenericLookup("V_YEAR")</Map>
                        <ReadOnly rtexprvalue="true">mb.isReadonly(2)</ReadOnly>
                    </ListBox>
                    <Label class="sTGBFBS">
                        <Caption> &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Jahre </Caption>
                    </Label>
                    <ListBox onchange="toggleAddressByAjax();">
                        <Name>APPLICATION_CUSTOMER.EMPLOYED_SINCE_MM!MLI</Name>
                        <Size>1</Size>
                        <Default rtexprvalue="true">mb.getValue("APPLICATION_CUSTOMER.EMPLOYED_SINCE_MM!MLI", "A")</Default>
                        <Map rtexprvalue="true">mb.getGenericLookup("V_MONTH")</Map>
                        <ReadOnly rtexprvalue="true">mb.isReadonly(2)</ReadOnly>
                    </ListBox>
                    <Label class="sTGBGBS">
                        <Caption> &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Monate </Caption>
                    </Label>
                    <ErrMsg/>
                </Cell>
            </DisclosureRowColor>
```

Comment: It's a problem with the XSLT. (Most likely placement of an `xsl:attribute`.)  Can you post the XSLT?

Comment: Ditto what DevNull said. You probably are trying to emit a node using `xsl:attribute` after emitting text or an element. You may have been using a different XSLT processor before, one that didn't complain about such things. Post your XSLT, and we'll help spot the problem. It should be fixable.

Comment: hi guys i just added source code...

Comment: Rather than `<xsl:variable name="..."><xsl:value-of select="..."/></xsl:variable>`, can you try just `<xsl:variable name="..." select="..." />` and see if that improves matters?

Comment: @IanRoberts u mean to do that for this code snippet or only for the offending scope?

Comment: Try it for the ones in that `<xsl:when>` to start with, but no reason not to change the others too if you think it's more readable.  I can't see anything wrong with the placement of your `<xsl:attribute>`, so I just wondered if maybe your processor was getting confused by the result tree fragments you're creating for your variables (using the `select` attribute on the variables will store the expression result in the variable directly rather than creating a fragment).

Comment: either that or move the `<xsl:attribute>` outside the outermost choose.

Comment: i played around with the offending condition `<xsl:when test="not(descendant::*[ErrMsg])">` and changed it to `<xsl:when test="not(descendant::*[ErrMsg][Name])">` and the error went away...but i dont know what negative impact there might be on legacy code..

Comment: Can you post a small sample of input XML that causes the problem? It should be a complete example and big enough that I can use it to reproduce the problem, but try to keep it as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* your problem might be the `<xsl:text>` nodes inside of your `<xsl:attribute>` element

```
<xsl:text><![CDATA[$err]]></xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
```

I think that should just say

```
<![CDATA[$err]]></xsl:attribute>
```

since you're creating an attribute, not a text node.

**Update:**
I tried to reproduce the error, but couldn't.  BUT, I did find that saxon was using whitespace in the attribute.  You might want to try Getting rid of some of the whitespace between some of the XSL elements.

```
<xsl:when test="not(descendant::*[ErrMsg])">
                <xsl:variable name="name"><xsl:value-of select="descendant::*[Name][position() = 1]/Name"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="parsed"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($name, '!')"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$parsed = ''"><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$parsed"/></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose><xsl:text><![CDATA[$err]]></xsl:text></xsl:attribute>   
            </xsl:when>
```

And this might solve your the actual error you're seeing:

```
  <div style="display:none;"><xsl:choose>
```

I think some text must be getting added to your 'div' element before the id attribute can be added.

Comment: Did you remove it from both places?  There were 2 occurrences.  Also, you might want to try removing each of the 'when' elements to narrow down exactly where the problem is.

Comment: yeah during XSLT, the XSLT processor pointed to me that it was at this line `<xsl:attribute name="id"><!--error here! -->`

Comment: oh i added `<!--error here-->` only in stackoverflow to help point out the specific line of the error.

Comment: i played around with the offending condition `<xsl:when test="not(descendant::*[ErrMsg])">` and changed it to `<xsl:when test="not(descendant::*[ErrMsg][Name])">` and the error went away...but i dont know what negative impact there might be on legacy code.

Comment: i copied and pasted your solutions and it worked! so why does the whitespace cause the problem, are there any docs to look it up? Thanks!