# xpath advanced syntax confusion

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<xsl:template name="makeDiv">   
    <xsl:when test="descendant::*[Parent][Name]">
    </xsl:when>  
</xsl:template>
```

somewhere down the line...

```
<xsl:if test="descendant::ParentCheck">
   <xsl:call-template name="makeDiv"/>
</xsl:if>
```

can some one explain to me what template-name=makeDiv is defined and what the test is doing? Is it looking for attributes '`Parent`' and '`Name`' of any nodes that is a descendant of `ParentCheck`?

Also, what does `<xsl:when test="not(descendant::*[SomeAttribute])">`  mean? Is it referring to other child elements that is NOT `SomeAttribute` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`descendant:*[Parent][Name]` means "Any descendant that has a child 'Parent' element AND a 'Name' element.

```
i.e. <SomeElement>
         <Parent/>
         <Name/>
     <SomeElement>
```

`descendant::ParentCheck` means "Any descendant named ParentCheck"

```
i.e. <ParentCheck />
```

Comment: thanks @Jakrabbit! i'll be really indebted if you can help me with XSL problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289248/xslt-attribute-node-id-cannot-be-created-after-the-children-of-the-containing

Comment: As `test` expressions, these two XPath expressions are evaluated as booleans, so that in effect they mean "*Does there exist* any descendant that ..."